# Progress bar update width when page load?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ruby-on-rails

When I load a page, I want to show a progress bar in a table field, like this:

```
<% @beacons.each do |beacon| %>
...
    <td><div id="progressbar" class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="10"
      aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:100%" ><%= beacon.power %>%</div></td>
```

but I can not `beacon.power` to update the width in progress bar, I don't need real time refresh, I just want when I load this page, the progress bar's width can use my db data: `beacon.power` to desplay

my website is

> IP/beacons

my controller:

```
  def index
    @beacons = Beacon.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { @beacons }
      format.json { @beacons }
    end
  end
```

I try to use javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.get("beacons.json", function(data){
      $("#progressbar").css('width', data.power+'%')
    }
    });
});
```

and it doesn't work , what wrong with my setting?

Comment: How do you know it doesn't work? If there's an error message, add its full text to your question.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe jQuery auto-parses the returned JSON from $.get method. I think you will likely need to do it manually. like this ...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.get("beacons.json", function(data){
      parsedData = $.parseJSON(data);
      $("#progressbar").css('width', parsedData.power + '%')
    }
    });
});
```